# Unable to create new forms in SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-list

I am using SharePoint online, and I am no longer able to create new forms in SharePoint designer 2013. I was doing it fine last week. But now it doesn't work in any of my lists.

[image: Could not save the list changes to the server.]

There are several other threads out there indicating solutions for this issue, but some of them only apply to on-premises, and others relate to a service health issue which ended last year.

I have checked for invalid lookup or calculated columns and there are none.
Custom scripts are enabled in the SharePoint admin center.

Answer (score 7):

Ability to create custom forms using designer is deprecated now in SharePoint Online from **Saturday, April 25, 2020**

https://thesharepointfarm.com/2020/04/sharepoint-designer-custom-forms-deprecation/

Awareness: SharePoint Designer feature deprecation

> MC210713, Stay Informed, Published date: Apr 25, 2020
>
> We’ve identified an issue affecting SharePoint Designer
>
> We’ve identified an issue affecting SharePoint Designer functionality
>   for creating and editing custom Forms within SharePoint Online. After
>   careful examination, we’ve determined that there is no known fix for
>   this issue and have elected to disable the feature effective as of
>   3:00 AM UTC on Saturday, April 25, 2020.
>
> Users who have previously leveraged SharePoint Designer to create
>   custom Forms are instead able to utilize PowerApps for this purpose.
>
> PowerApps is an easy and powerful tool that allows users operating in
>   the SharePoint Online Modern experience to create and edit custom
>   Forms for SharePoint lists and document libraries right from a browser
>   window. PowerApps does not require traditional coding knowledge or any
>   additional app downloads such as InfoPath.
>
> *Note: SharePoint Online Classic users will need to temporarily switch to the Modern experience to access and utilize PowerApps; though, all
>   custom Forms created in PowerApps are accessible by SharePoint Online
>   Classic experience users.

Comment: Wow so they disabled it on the weekend. Here I thought it was me.

Comment: Power apps /spfxis the way to go now. Hope you could make the switch over easily, unless there are some heavy custom features in the form